# Celery only responding Sending due tasks

Tags: django, celery

I followed this [instruction](https://www.merixstudio.com/blog/django-celery-beat/) on how to implement Celery with Django. However, after everything done, on my terminal it just repeating `Sending due tasks "NAME" users.tasks.send_import_summary**strong text**`. Note. I added an HttpResponse and checking with my browser that the response was a success and on terminal, I can see the TEST printed. But when I run celery, it does nothing.

Here is what I did:

tasks.py

```
from celery import task 
from celery import shared_task 
def send_import_summary():
    test_function() # prints a TEST on terminal
    return HttpResponse("NONE")
```

project's init.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from .celery import celery_app as celery_app   
__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

apps' init.py

```
default_app_config = 'users.apps.UsersConfig'
```

settings.py

```
from celery.schedules import crontab   
BROKER_URL = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://localhost:6379'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'
```

celery.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals 
import os 
from celery import Celery 
from django.conf import settings
celery_app = Celery('proj')
celery_app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
celery_app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

terminal:

[image]

Admin:

[image]

Checked other SO/Articles regarding celery, I tried running `celery -A proj beat`　and read about this `Received unregistered task of type` error message.

**UPDATE** As per requested by Connans, here is my worker before and after running beat.

before:

[image]

After [image]

Comment: could you include a screenshot of this terminal output you are getting please

Comment: Thank you for showing interest in my concern. I have added both terminal and admin page SS.

Comment: @rodjames What are you expecting to happen ? Did you check the time interval ? Is the celery worker running ?

Comment: I am expecting it to print in terminal. The same with the tutorial that I used.

Comment: If it prints on my terminal, then I can make other things work with it.

Comment: @Conans. I think it is running since I can see `Sending due tasks TASK_NAME` when I enter command `celery -A proj beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler`

Comment: @rodjames Sending tasks is the job of celery beat, do you see the worker receiving/processing it ?

Comment: I am new to this so I dont know if my answer to your question is correct. I uploaded an image of my terminal in the question. If you are talking about something else, please let me know.

Comment: @Conans. i run celery -A proj worker and i can see that it is receiving the tasks. But I cant see if processing.

Comment: @rodjames What does your `test_function` do ? Also, celery tasks should return serializable responses. Can you attach your celery worker output here ?

Comment: @Conans. Added my worker before and after running beat. Please note that I changed notification to summary.

Answer (score 0):

Good day.

After searching other SO/Articles, I found this to run worker together with beat.

Run Celery Worker:

```
celery -A proj worker -l info --without-gossip --without-mingle --without-heartbeat -Ofair --pool=solo
```

Run Celery Beat:

```
celery -A proj beat -l info  --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

This now makes beat send the task and worker to receive and process it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Cheers.